# Create Language Service for VisualStudio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-addins, vs-extensibility

I want to build a language service for visual studio 2010. I was first trying to follow the tutorial and documentations from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166533.aspx).

The problem is i don't succeed to make this works (i'll explain later my problem). So i digged into existing implementations, i found [Ook!](http://resources.devx.com/MSDN/Article/45058) and [lua](http://vslua.codeplex.com/) . both of these projects doesn't use the tutorial or documentation i found on MSDN, but something based on MEF. Lua used this only with previous Visual Studio versions.

So i'm wondering if i'm using an obsolete method to create a language service (But the documentation aims Visual Studio 2010), or there is different ways to do this, which depends on needs.

In my case, i've got a language that doesn't need to be compiled into cli, but i want to have an editor that have colorization, syntax warnings and errors, intellisense ...

The problem i mentionned is that when launching exp instance, there is no text editor with my file extension, and visual studio begins to have many lags. The language service is registered using 3 attributes : ProvideServiceAttribute, ProvideLanguageServiceAttribute and ProvideLanguageServiceExtension. Also initialized in Package intialize method, like mentionned in [Proffer the Language](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166498.aspx).... The package is loaded when i try to open the file with my extension, the language service is initialized.

So i don't get it why i does not work, could you please help me to understand how language service works, and what is the best way to implement it

Thanks

Comment: Actually, the MEF way is the new way.

Answer (score 1):

Good chance your `IScanner` implementation has an endless loop, happened to me.